# Shadow only on elpsis

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have the following widget

```
import 'dart:collection';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

@immutable
class StrokeText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Color color;
  final Color strokeColor;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final TextStyle? style;
  final TextOverflow? overflow;

  const StrokeText(
    this.text, {
    Key? key,
    this.color = Colors.white,
    this.strokeColor = Colors.black,
    this.strokeWidth = 1,
    this.style,
    this.overflow,
  }) : super(key: key);

  List<Shadow> outlinedText({
    double strokeWidth = 2,
    Color strokeColor = Colors.black,
    int precision = 5,
  }) {
    Set<Shadow> result = {};
    for (int x = 1; x < strokeWidth + precision; x++) {
      for (int y = 1; y < strokeWidth + precision; y++) {
        double offsetX = x.toDouble();
        double offsetY = y.toDouble();
        result.add(Shadow(offset: Offset(-strokeWidth / offsetX, -strokeWidth / offsetY), color: strokeColor));
        result.add(Shadow(offset: Offset(-strokeWidth / offsetX, strokeWidth / offsetY), color: strokeColor));
        result.add(Shadow(offset: Offset(strokeWidth / offsetX, -strokeWidth / offsetY), color: strokeColor));
        result.add(Shadow(offset: Offset(strokeWidth / offsetX, strokeWidth / offsetY), color: strokeColor));
      }
    }
    return result.toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      text,
      overflow: overflow,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: style?.fontSize,
        fontWeight: style?.fontWeight,
        fontFamily: style?.fontFamily,
        height: style?.height,
        wordSpacing: style?.wordSpacing,
        color: color,
        shadows: outlinedText(
          strokeColor: strokeColor,
          strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Which displays shadows behind text, which works great. But once the text overflows the shadow will only be on the elipsis. Does anyone know why this happens?

[image]